# MVC 4 data annotations Validators concept , failure or please suggest how to resolve

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

In our project we are using DataAnnotaions for input validations. Our validators regular implementing 
IClientValidatable and seems to work good.

Now we have a case that implementation of IClientValidatable is impossible ,and only server validation could be implemented.

The problem I've  faced is the problem of default binding , lets say I have textbox that user should put a dateTime in this field , user puts not valid type for DateTime , say "23453452345" , in this case Default binding is failed to bind value to viewmodel type typeof(DateTime) , and throws generic error about that type mismatch or something. And the main problem is that value user put in txtbox dissapears from textbox becuase binding failed.

So it brakes the regular user experience , and breaks the "accessibility" , that is very important for our company.

The question is how are dealing with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can use jquery.validate with custom rules for client-side validation. For server side i'd recommend using a string field for DateTime value, which you would try to cast to DateTime in your model binder and rise validation error if it's not correct (actually you can use custom model binders). So you'l always keep wrong value after form validation was't successfull

**upd**: For implementing custom model binder you need following steps (didn't really check code, let me know if there are any errors):

in global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(your_model_type), new YourModelTypeBinder());
}
```

so now you need class YourModelTypeBinder as:

```
public class YourModelTypeBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) as YourModelType;

        if (model != null)
        {
            if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix("DateTimeString"))
            {
                ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
                try
                {
                    var s = valueResult.ConvertTo(string);
                    var valid = DateTime.TryParse(s, out model.RealDateTime);
                    if (!valid)
                        bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("DateTimeString", "Not a valid date");
                }
                catch
                {
                    bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("DateTimeString", "Not a valid date");
                }
            }
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sergio , could you please point to good article about Custom model binders , google gives me same looking simple examples for this.

Comment: I'l try to provide you a sample, give me a little time for it

Comment: P.S using string field for DateTime doen't seems for me good option , but maybe I am mistaken.